# Excel 2013 C# interop select range not working

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-automation

I am converting an existing C# program from Excel 2003 to Excel 2013 (Office 365). It uses the excel interop interface. The application contains its own copy of the Interop.Excel.dll (v11.0.8161), i.e. it's not linked into the assembly installed on the local machine. It runs OK as it is on a machine with 2013 installed, apart from two methods; Range.Select() and WorkBook.BreakLink(). The first throws an exception of "Select method of Range class failed" and the second "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC". Replacing the interop dll with version 15.0.4641 (from Office 2013) makes no difference, the errors still occur. Code snippets are as follows;

```
private Excel.Workbook NewWB;

Excel.Worksheet lastSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)NewWB.Worksheets[NewWB.Worksheets.Count];
((Excel.Range)lastSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Select();

Array links = NewWB.LinkSources(Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks) as Array;
    if (links != null)
        foreach (var l in links)
            NewWB.BreakLink((string)l, Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
```

Does anyone know why just these two methods would fail when the application works otherwise; it loads multiple workbooks, extracts specific worksheets and then merges them into a new workbook? From the Microsoft documentation these methods still work as they did previously.

Comment: this looks very incomplete... can you show the full code block or can you specify and or tell us what line the error is actually happening.. also can you get this to work locally when debugging the code.. I have a feeling that you have 2 things going on here 1 could be a GAC issue the other could be you're not setting the Copy Local = true on the actual version of the Interop.dll but it's hard to determine based on what you have posted here...

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Since posting I've discovered that 'NewWB.ActiveSheet.Range("a1", "a1").Select();' works for the selection. I would guess that this is something to do with the Select only working on the active sheet. I'm working in VS 2012 which doesn't seem to have the 'Copy Local' option, the Microsoft documentation only shows it for 2005/2008/2010 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I think it's just a syntax as it rather should be `(Excel.Range)lastSheet.Cells[1, 1].Select();`

Comment: The Cells property doesn't have a Select method, so that doesn't compile. The BreakLink problem turned out to be that the source Excel workbook had square brackets in it's filename. Changing them to curly brackets fixed it. All things that worked fine in 2003, but have changed in 2013.